# ASP.NET Autoloading user controls without web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, autoload

Hi I've got to do autoloading in asp.net 2.0 (but if it's impossible please show me for higher version). In aspx files I've got normal tags like

```
<aaa:BBB ID="ccc" runat="server" />
```

I've also in web.config added controls like system.web->pages->controls->

```
<add src="zzz" tagName = "BBB" tagPrefix="aaa" />
```

I would like to not add lines to web.config cause I've got lots and lots of user controls for specific projects and it's getting messy.

What I would like? Autoloader :) Maybe some fine tuning of web.config? I know that web.config is parsed into some classes which manage it. You can even write to this classes, but you also write to web.config file...increasing it's size :(

Comment: What about using `<@ Register ...@>`?

Comment: Still not dynamic approach...still you have to know what to register :( Or...you can register autoloader ;)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no auto loader for asp.net template controls. eg: SharePoint has lots of template based controls (ascx), and each one has to be registered individually.

You don't have to register every control in web.config though, you can register them just on the page that uses them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to bypass this approach by web.config...and now I want to bypass web.config ;)

Comment: those two options are the only way